# remove all leading and trailing and blank spaces

Tags: powershell

I want to trim whitespace characters from both the front and back of lines in a text file and blank spaces at the beginning and end of the text file.

```
$content = Get-Content C:\temp\file.txt
$content | Foreach {$_.TrimEnd()} | Set-Content C:\temp\file.txt
```

Text file :

```
      Data2\
            Data2\Documents\
                  Data2\Documents\1.txt
                  Data2\Documents\2.txt
                  Data2\Documents\3.txt
                  Data2\Documents\4.txt
                  Data2\Documents\5.txt
                  Data2\Documents\shares.reg
      Data2\Documents\TEST\
                    Data2\Documents\TEST\5.txt
```

So I would like to above to be like this:

```
Data2\
Data2\Documents\
Data2\Documents\1.txt
Data2\Documents\2.txt
Data2\Documents\3.txt
Data2\Documents\4.txt
Data2\Documents\5.txt
Data2\Documents\shares.reg
Data2\Documents\TEST\
Data2\Documents\TEST\5.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read a file as an array, you can filter out blank lines using comparison operator `-ne`. You can remove a line's leading and trailing white space with the `Trim()` method.

```
(Get-Content file.txt).Trim() -ne '' | Set-Content file.txt
```

Applying `Trim()` before the comparison will remove blank lines and lines with only white space. If you want white space lines to still appear as blank lines, you can reverse the operations:

```
((Get-Content file.txt) -ne '').Trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

Load text from `original.txt`, trim the whitespace and save result to `trimmed.txt`.

```bsh
(Get-Content original.txt).Trim() | Set-Content trimmed.txt
```

Comment: how to remove  blank spaces at the beginning and end of the text file?